# MATLAB: Plot integral using quad/quadl

Tags: matlab, plot, integral

I would like to know if anybody knows how I can plot an integral calculated using quad/quadl, or if this is possible.

I read that I can set the trace parameter to be non-zero, and this results in the information of each iteration being provided, but I'm not sure how and if I can use the information to plot an integral.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

quad and quadl do not compute an integral function anyway, i.e., an integral as a function of the parameter. And since tools like this work iteratively, refining their estimate until it satisfies a tolerance on the global value, they are not easily made to produce the plot you desire.

You can do what you desire by using a differential equation solver to generate the solution, ode45 for example.